# Is ID paired with token redundant in this case?

Tags: security, server

I'm working on a project I made a year ago, and I actually forget what I was thinking at that time.

There is a communication between my server and my customer's server via HTTP POST.

My server send a list telling customer's server which data I need, every requested data has an unique ID, and customer's server send back a list of ID, data pair.

For example: My server send

```
[{id: 1001, input: 40.2},
 {id: 2033, input: 326.4},
 {id: 4212, input: 67.12},
 {id: 9551, input: 5.3}]
```

My customer's server respond

```
[{id: 1001, output: 3144},
 {id: 2033, output: 4362},
 {id: 4212, output: 6428},
 {id: 9551, output: 2319}]
```

My customer's server can respond an empty list, and then send the data later via another API.

To prevent customer's server receiving fake request, my server will send a `key` along with the list. Customer can see that key in console page and set it into their server.

To prevent our server receiving fake response or fake data submission, customer need to send their `Customer ID` and `API key` along with the responding list. They can see it in console page.

The weird thing is, the list entries not only have `id`, but also have a randomly generated `token`. So the lists actually look like this.

My server send

```
[{id: 1001, token: dgkldjktle34512fas, input: 40.2},
 {id: 2033, token: gt23k4652bkjte24ks, input: 326.4},
 {id: 4212, token: 35wfvjnsl34342ldsa, input: 67.12},
 {id: 9551, token: eftrlh44yw3.dflk3r, input: 5.3}]
```

My customer's server respond

```
[{id: 1001, token: dgkldjktle34512fas, output: 3144},
 {id: 2033, token: gt23k4652bkjte24ks, output: 4362},
 {id: 4212, token: 35wfvjnsl34342ldsa, output: 6428},
 {id: 9551, token: eftrlh44yw3.dflk3r, output: 2319}]
```

If the responding data has wrong token, my server will not accept it.

But now I'm confusing, why I need the token in list?

The `API key` checking already prevents fake response or fake data submission.

Is it a useless redundancy? Or is there a scenario that I thought of before, but forget now?

Answer (score 0):

The token prevents you receiving a response without actually requesting anything, a tiny bit similar to CSRF. Note though that your scheme of sending around keys for authentication could be improved. Currently if I understand correctly a man in the middle attacker (which could be a proxy, even in case of https (tls), which this always should be) can change values, whereas the shared secret could be used to apply message authentication (eg. HMAC) to provide assurance that the data is really what was sent in either direction.